# Openssl verify -CAfile bouncycastle equivalent

Tags: java, openssl, bouncycastle, verify

I would like to know which is the equivalent(if exist) for Bouncycastle library of the following command:

> openssl verify -CAfile cert1.pem cert2.pem

Any other Java lib solution is welcome.